# parsing an online document (xml file) in gtk

Tags: gtk, libxml2

how do i parse an online document (xml file) in gtk, for example the url : http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml contains the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use two auxiliary libraries of GTK to do this: [libsoup](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libsoup/stable/) to download the document, and [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-lib.html) to parse it.